# How to get ViewPager indicator onClick in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want `ViewPager` to swipe base on its `indicator` click. I have used JakeWharton's [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) for `ViewPager indicator` but I have not fine any proper solution as per my requirement. I have seen many question on this site regarding that but not get any proper solution. Can anyone help me how can I get such functionality by click on `indicator` `view pager` should be swipe. Below in my MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Integer> alPhoto;
    private CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadArrayList();

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,alPhoto);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set for ViewPager indicator.
        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        mIndicator.setSnap(true);

    }

    private void loadArrayList() {
        try {
            alPhoto = new ArrayList<>();
            alPhoto.add(R.drawable.first);
            alPhoto.add(R.drawable.second);
            alPhoto.add(R.drawable.third);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and Here is my Adapter.

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Integer> alPhoto;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context mainActivity,ArrayList<Integer> alPhoto) {
        this.context= mainActivity;
        this.alPhoto=alPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return alPhoto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        ImageView imgflag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,false);

        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        imgflag.setImageResource(alPhoto.get(position));

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sakib just set the current postion on Onclick

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set onClick listener to handle click on your indicator?
Like this:

```
private OnClickListener mIndicatorListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // handle your click
    }
};
mIndicator.setOnClickListener(mIndicatorListener);
```

Comment: I can get click by your method but I need to set `viewpager` also base on click of indicator so how can I get such functionality.

Comment: You need to switch page by click on indicator, i got you right? If yes, then you need to get position of every indicator and put `viewPager.setCurrentItem( positionOfSelectedIndicator )` in onClickListener

Comment: Yes I need to set `view pager` on `indicator`'s clicked position but I am unable to get correct position of `mIndicator click`. Please help me to how can I get such functionality.